# Disable Scroll button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please help me to rectify the below code snippet, Right click disable is working fine ,but Middle button(Scroll button) Disable is not working.It shows the message but after clicking [ok] to alert box. It will open in new tab.And i am using Firefox browser Thank you

```js
function clickIE()
{
    if (document.all) 
    {
        alert("Right click is disabled2");
        return false;
    }
}
function clickNS(e) 
{  
    if(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) 
    {
        if (e.which==3)
        {
            alert("Right click is disabled1");
            e.preventDefault();            
            return false;
        }
        if(e.which==2)
        {
            alert("Right click is disabled3");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (document.layers)
{
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS;
}
else
{
    document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;
}
    document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello world</a>
```

Comment: `document.layers`? Now that is a name that I haven't heard in a long time...

Comment: _“Right click disable is working fine”_ – please don’t do nonsense like this, it just decreases the usability of any site massively …

Comment: Please read my Question carefully, i said scroll Button click is not working properly

Comment: @CBroe I would disagree, if you were trying to prevent the normal right click menu from popping up, or if you wanted to make it harder for people to copy images!

Comment: Could you make a plnker or jsfiddle completely demonstrating the problem. Your code snippet is hard to work with...

Comment: @CallumLinington that does not prevent “stealing images” in any way. Even by taking a simply screenshot I basically _have_ your images. But it decreases usability massively. Even in the above minimal snippet, I could f.e. not use my browser context menu to open the link in a new tab - because pure idi*cy in form of a “na-ah, don’t do that” alert prevents me from completing that action.

Comment: @CBroe mate, I said make it harder. But it doesn't matter what either of us think on the subject of right click, this is a QA site.

Comment: i am working on a HR Product ERP Website, so i need this function Badly.@CBroe

Answer (score 0):

I would move `e.preventDefault()` to the top of the method:

```
function clickNS(e) 
{  
    e.preventDefault();

    if(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) 
    {
        if (e.which==3)
        {
            alert("Right click is disabled1");

            return false;
        }
        if(e.which==2)
        {
            alert("Right click is disabled3");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Because what happens if the first condition isn't met?!

Comment: if i move e.preventDefault to the top it doesn't work, because e.which==2 satisfies the scroll button click

Comment: No change! Problem still remains same

Comment: Does it fix this _It shows the message but after clicking [ok] to alert box. It will open in new tab_

Comment: Yes sir,@Callum It is OPening in new tab after clicking OK